# Does the plot of the Season Five Finale of Dexter have serious flaws?

Tags: plot-explanation, dexter

In the Season Five finale of *Dexter*, entitled "The Big One," there appears to be a fatal plot flaw.

Recall that Dexter used a car, which he had stolen near the crime scene where he killed Stan Liddy, to rescue Lumen.  Upon arriving at the camp where Jordan had kidnapped Lumen, Dexter has a car accident in which the stolen car actually spins and rolls violently out of control.  That car isn't going anywhere.  Certainly, Dexter and Lumen could not have possibly taken care of the stolen car after killing Jordan.

Next, Debra arrives at the crime scene where Dexter and Lumen have just killed Jordan.  She permits Dexter and Lumen to flee, but states that she will "call it in."

Investigating officers should have seen the stolen vehicle, matched it to a reported missing/stolen vehicle (stolen near the Liddy crime scene that Dexter had recently inexplicably fled), and continued to pursue that lead.

Quinn would have certainly become more curious about anything that would potentially exonerate him from Liddy's murder.  And the fraudulent results Dexter reported regarding the blood found on Quinn's shoe doesn't seem adequate to excuse Quinn as a suspect.

So, why was this evidence never investigated further?

Comment: It's been a while since I watched, but did Deb actually call it in? One of the funny things about the way Dexter is writen, including it's fantasy/fairy tale references laced through out, is that there are several things that one might think will trip Dexter up and one never knows for certian what shoe is going to be the one to drop (like how did Dex's season 5 neighbor not figure something out? LOL!). Without giving the series finale away, one thing that remains true, is that no matter what Dexter does, things tend to not go as planned, but yet he sometimes gets away with ridiculous things.

Comment: Why did you roll back all the edits? That is not the way we write a question here.

Comment: @nogshine I'll post a question as I see fit.  The prior edits did nothing to improve its content and I don't appreciate the interference.

Comment: Please don't use show titles in the question title the way you are. It's non-standard and is discouraged on this site. Please use tags to mark the show title and feel free to include it in the body. Additionally, TV show titles should be in italics with the episode titles in quotes. These changes are correct, so rolling them back is destructive to your question.

Comment: @catija I"ll post a question as I see fit.  I have more than 115 K reputation points on The Math Stack Exchange.  So, please refrain from admonoshing me as to the "correct" way to pose a question.  And why should one remove the word "fatal" from the main body?

Comment: You know... your rep on Math SE doesn't mean any more than my two mod diamonds on other sites do... here. You're new to this community. It'd behoove you to stop trying to pull rank on the long-standing high-rep users who know how **this** site works.

Comment: @MarkViola of your 115,030 rep on Maths, only 265 rep comes from 6 question. you can stop your bragging since rep != ability to ask questions because if it did then you'd have to admit you have little experience in asking questions and whole lot more in answering them

Comment: @MarkViola Stop rollbacking when people are helping your post and you don't have to be over protective and rude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, why was this evidence never investigated further?

### Dexter and Lumen most likely moved/hid the car using the construction machinery before leaving Camp Jordan.

When Dexter went flying off the road, it was because he was about to run into some construction machinery; a Case 580M backhoe loader.

[image]

Using the very loader that caused him to wreck, Dexter and Lumen would have pushed the car off the main road that leads into camp, and then covered it up with dirt/sticks/leaves/etc..

***But, how do we know the backhoe loader works?***

Closer towards the beginning of the episode, Jordan Chase visits the camp with Lumen in the trunk. As he's first driving into camp, he pays notice to the backhoe loader, which is neatly out of the way of the road.

Fast-forward to when Dexter arrives at the camp, and loader is in the middle of the road, with one of the buckets raised.

Obviously, Jordan Chase move the machinery to the middle of the road [to set a trap for Dexter], thus proving it was functional for Dexter and Lumen to then use to move the wrecked car.

Comment: Debra claimed that police would be arriving in an hour.  Is it plausible that Dexter and Lumen could carve up Jordan, move the car with a machine they have no knowledge of using, cover it so well that investigators wouldn't stumble upon it, then flee the scene on foot (or would they take the BMW and have to dispose of it)?

Comment: @MarkViola *" .. or would they take the BMW and have to dispose of it.."* -- Dexter explicitly mentions that they'll use Jordan's car to move the body (after Lumen asks if they'll leave the body there). That being said, Dexter didn't dismember Jordan at the camp. Instead, he put Jordan Chase in the BMW, used the machinery to move/hide the wrecked car, and then they both left in the BMW. Dexter and Lumen could have *literally* covered the entire car with dirt, and with Dexter being fairly intelligent, I don't see it being too difficult for him in roughly an hour's time.

Comment: And Dexter was able to find the "keys" to the bulldozer, learn how to deftly operate it to move an automobile, find a location for which a huge pile of "new" dirt would go completely undiscovered by the police, prepare Jordan's body with DNA-proof wrap and then drag his dead body to his BWM, drive to a location that wouldn't be near the marina, find alternative transportation to the Marina, move Jordan's body from the BMW to the "new car," etc.  I don't find it plausible.  And where was Debra during this purported evidence tampering?

Comment: But (+1) for your imagination and depth of knowledge of details in the episode.

Comment: @MarkViola It could be suggested that the keys to the loader were still in the cabin, since the camp was abandoned, and since Jordan had used it just a few minutes prior to Dexter getting there. If the keys weren't in the cabin of the loader, they would either be on Jordan Chase's body (along with the BMW keys, which were also needed), or on a countertop in the cabin.

Comment: @MarkViola As for the moving of Jordan's body and the removal of any DNA.. Dexter is a seasoned murderer and a professional crime scene analyst; cleaning up that single (and very dirty) room that Jordan was killed it wouldn't pose a problem to Dexter. Throughout the series, we've seen Dexter do quite extraordinary things in attempts to cover his tracks, and his plans nearly always work. Disposing of the BMW and body, and remaining discreet about, it is well within his repertoire of abilities. TY for the +1, I really enjoy the Dexter series. :)

Comment: @MarkViola - you are inventing requirements that don't necessarily have to be followed. Why do I have to drive to a location not near the marina and transfer? Can't I drive to the marina, then move the car elsewhere later? Why would the police magically be going straight to the marina based on..... nothing, or, at the very least, based on bits of evidence that have to be analyzed and pieced together over a period of hours or days? How DNA-proof does my wrap have to be? What if a bit of DNA falls or leaks out at some random spot? What are the odds of it being located and recognized? Etc.

Comment: I wasn't doubtIng Dexter's capabilities.  He just wouldn't have enogh time

Comment: @poleholeset You're missing the bigger picture.  Dexter had a lot more things to do than normal given the burden of the stolen car.  And Debra had stated they had an hour or so to be gone.  I don't find a plausible way to do all that needed to be done in that short a time frame.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet And lest you forget, LaGuerta had a "stake and notify," which included 24-hour surveillance, on Chase.  So, his BMW, wherever it might be, would be potentially spotted by an already alerted police force.

Comment: @MarkViola Within the hour's time, Dexter and Lumen would need to do the following: (1) wrap up Jordan's body and carry it to the car; 10min. (2a) move the wrecked car with the loader; 40min. (2b) clean the room of evidence; 20min. (3) drive away; 5min. Total time: 55min. In the case of 2a and 2b, at this point, Lumen has become quite familiar with the procedures and precautions that Dexter goes through when preparing/cleaning a room, and so, Dexter would move the car while Lumen cleans the room. IMO, it seems more probable than not, especially when compared to other events in the series.

Comment: @MarkViola As for the disposal of the car and body, I would think that's off-topic w.r.t. the OP. If I'm to understand it correctly, the focus of the OP is to question why the stolen vehicle was never found, and subsequently, linked to Liddy's murder. IMO, the events that take place after Dexter leaves the camp aren't  relevant when providing a response to this question. Don't you agree?

Comment: Well, if one's answer to the original question suggests that the car was disposed/hidden, then it is natural to inquire as to how that's plausible.  Your time line and explanation are solid.  And so I'm likely to accept your answer inevitably.